# How can i convert a string to treeview node and then remove the node from the treeview?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have this code:

```
RemoveDirectory(path, true);
TreeNode nodetoremove = new TreeNode(path);
UpdateTreeview(nodetoremove);
```

For example in the variable path(string) i have: root\files
This is a path on my ftp server that i deleted.
Now i want to remove/delete the node name files from my treeView1
In this case it's only one node under root: root\files
In my treeView1 strcture is also built like this the main root is called root and under it all the structore.

So i have on my treeView root and under it files.

There might be cases that in path i will have for example: root\files\files1\files2
And then i will want to delete from the treeView the node files2 so root files files1 will keep only files2 to be deleted.

So i tried to do:

```
TreeNode nodetoremove = new TreeNode(path);
UpdateTreeview(nodetoremove);
```

And inside UpdateTreeview i did:

```
private void UpdateTreeview(TreeNode DirToRemove)
        {           
                treeViewMS1.Nodes.Remove(DirToRemove);  
        }
```

But it dosen't delete the node i keep see it in the treeView.

In general i want to delete what in path as node in treeView1.

This is how i select a node:

```
private void treeViewMS1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                treeViewMS1.SelectedNode = treeViewMS1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);

                if (treeViewMS1.SelectedNode != null)
                {
                    menuStrip.Show(treeViewMS1, e.Location);
                }
            }
        }
```

So if i selected in the treeView for exmaple the node root\test1\test2\test3 i selected clicked on test3 it should remove from the treeView only test3

If i selected the node test2 it should remove test2 and test3 and files inside if there are any.

And if i selected only test1 then move it all test1\test2\test3
It does delete them as i describe here from the ftp server right but the problem is to remove it from the treeView visualy.

The rule in general is to remove the selected node and every sub nodes inside the selected one.

Comment: Try using the `TreeView.Nodes.Find(nodeKey, searchAllChildren)` function to find the node.  Your Remove code doesn't work because you aren't comparing strings, you are comparing nodes, which will never be the same reference.

Comment: How do i use the Find ? TreeNode[] nodetoremove = treeViewMS1.Nodes.Find(path, true); ? And then UpdateTreeview(nodetoremove); ?

Comment: You didn't show how you are adding the nodes, but the nodes have to have their name property set for the search to work (I believe).  The function returns an array of nodes, so if it returns one node, it found the one you want to remove from the parent collection.

Comment: Seen your code update. Could you upload also a screenshot and/or picture of your form with the treeview and nodes? For me it is still hard to conceive.

Comment: Sjipse i can't post add images here i'm in level 1 user. So here is a link for the screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/e2gfzet3d/ you can see in this case i selected the node test then i did right click and clicked on Delete this deleted from my ftp server the file name lightning1.jpg and then the node test. Now i want to do the same with the treeView1 to delete/remove from the treeView the selected node and all sub nodes and files inside. And if i was selecting sameah(in the screenshot) then it should remove from the treeView the image lightning1.jpg then test and in the end sameah.

Comment: And if for example under test there was another node(directory) called test1 and i was selecting test1 then it should remove from the treeView only test1 and whatever inside test1 and leave sameah and test and lightning1.jpg.

Comment: Sjips again link for the screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/e2gfzet3d/

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the node first and then remove it. For example, like this:

```
TreeNode[] nodes = treeViewMS1.Nodes.Find("folder\\files", true);
if (nodes.Count() > 0)
{
    if (nodes[0].Parent != null)
        nodes[0].Parent.Nodes.Remove(nodes[0]);
    else          
        treeViewMS1.Nodes.Remove(nodes[0]);
}
```

The `Find` function returns an array. I assume that the node that you have to find is unique. In that case, there will be only one element in the array.
Note that you need to use `\\` for `\`, or use `@`.

Comment: @LarsTech: I think you're right. I will update the code snippet.

Comment: The problem is when i'm doing this:  RemoveDirectory(path, true);
            TreeNode[] nodes = treeViewMS1.Nodes.Find(path, true); if the i want to move the main node for example in path i see now: root\\jonnaisthatyou\\1\\2\\3 i want to delete now jonnaisthatyou including all sub directories and files . But in fact it's trying to delete root\\jonnaisthatyou\\1\\2\\3 and in 3 there is only one file so it return nodes.Count() 0 the idea was to remove from the treeView the selected node. I will show in my question what i mean.

Comment: Edited my question with how i select the nodes. And i want to remove from the treeView only the selected node and every sub nodes/files inside from the treeView.